# My Random Forest Classification Algorithm doesn't give the results I want

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I made up a excel sheet of random numbers (3000 rows and 6 columns) and set it so any row having a B column >= 50, a C column of 0 and an E column of 1 gets a final 'y' value of 1. Else, it gets a 0 value. Ran this through this RandomForestClassifier code and it doesn't work and either returns 0 for all new test data or doesn't even take into account the B column when predicting. How can I solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import pickle


data_crd = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Rada1\.spyder-py3\new_created_data.csv')
#C:\Users\Rada1\.spyder-py3\new_created_data.csv
data_crd.head()


X = data_crd.iloc[:,1:5]
y = data_crd.iloc[:,5]

#print (X)
#print (y)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)

sc = StandardScaler()

X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators = 500, random_state = 0)
classifier.fit (X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print (classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print (confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print (accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))


with open ('model_wcd','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(classifier,f)
```

I get a 100% accuracy rate as my result which just already feels wrong. What do I need to adjust?

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00       515
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00        85

    accuracy                           1.00       600
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       600
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       600

[[515   0]
 [  0  85]]
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully if you use stratify =y it might work
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state=0,stratify=y)
and also use MinMaxScaler for numerical feature and reshape them to (-1,1)
x_train_num=num_feature.transform(x_train[column_name].values.reshape(-1,1))
x_test_num=num_feature.transform(x_test[column_name].values.reshape(-1,1))